# C: copying some structs causes strange behavior

Tags: c

I have an annoying bug in the line

```
rq->tickets[rq->usedContracts] = toAdd;
```

if i do:    `rq->tickets[0] = toAdd` the program crashes

if i do     `rq->tickets[1] = toAdd;` it works

valgrind says

> ==19501== Use of uninitialised value of size 8

and

> ==19501== Invalid write of size 8

for this very line. What is wrong?

```
    struct TS_element {
    int travels;
    int originalTravels;
    int cost;
    char** dates;
    int moneyLeft;
} TicketSet;

struct RQ_element {
    int usedContracts;

    struct TS_element* tickets;
} RabQav;



TicketSetStatus tsCreate(TicketSet* t, int n, int c) {
    if (n <= 0)
    return TS_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER;
    TicketSet* myTicketSet = (TicketSet*) malloc(sizeof(TicketSet));
    if (myTicketSet == NULL) {
        return TS_CANNOT_CREATE;
    }
    myTicketSet->usedTravels = 0;
    myTicketSet->originalTravels = n;
    myTicketSet->cost = c;
    myTicketSet->moneyLeft = n * c;
    char**  dates =  malloc(sizeof(char**)* (n)); //todo maybe c99 allows dynamic arrays?
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dates[i] =  malloc(sizeof(char)*GOOD_LENGTH+1);
        if (dates[i] == NULL) {
            free(dates);  
            free(t);
            return TS_CANNOT_CREATE;
        }
    }


    myTicketSet->dates = dates;
    *t = *myTicketSet;

    return TS_SUCCESS;
}


static void copyTicketSets(TicketSet* dest, const TicketSet* source) {

    dest->usedTravels = source->usedTravels;
    dest->originalTravels = source->originalTravels;
    dest->cost = source->cost;
    dest->moneyLeft = source->moneyLeft;

    for (int i = 0; i < source->originalTravels; i++) {
        if (NULL != source->dates[i]) {
            free(dest->dates[i]);
            dest->dates[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * GOOD_LENGTH + 1);
            if (dest->dates[i] == NULL) {
                free(dest->dates); //todo free dates 0...i-1
                free(dest);
                return;
            }
            strcpy(dest->dates[i], source->dates[i]);
        }

    }

}
RabQavStatus rqLoadTS(RabQav* rq, TicketSet t, DateTime dt) {


    TicketSet toAdd;
    TicketSetStatus res = tsCreate(&toAdd, t.originalTravels, t.cost);
    if (res != TS_SUCCESS) {
        return RQ_FAIL;
    }

    copyTicketSets(&toAdd, &t);  
    rq->tickets[rq->usedContracts] = toAdd;
    rq->usedContracts++;
    return RQ_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Can you show us where `rq->tickets` is assigned?

Comment: [code]RabQavStatus rqCreate(RabQav* rq) {
 RabQav* rabQav = (RabQav*) malloc(sizeof(RabQav));
 if (rabQav == NULL) {
  return RQ_CANNOT_CREATE;
 }

 /*for(int i=0;i<MAX_CONTRACTS;i++){
  TicketSet* toAdd = malloc(sizeof(*toAdd) * (MAX_CONTRACTS)); //todo if null
  rq->tickets[i] = toAdd;
  }*/
 rabQav->usedContracts = 0;
 rq->tickets=malloc(sizeof(TicketSet)*MAX_CONTRACTS);
 *rq = *rabQav;

 return RQ_SUCCESS;
}[/code]

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of the issues:

```
TicketSetStatus tsCreate(TicketSet* t, int n, int c) {
```

How can you pass `tsCreate` a `TicketSet*`? It *creates* a ticket set. So the pointer to the ticket set isn't known on entry.

```
*t = *myTicketSet;
```

This sets the value of `t` to the value of `myTicketSet`. But you wanted to return a pointer to the new ticket set, not its value.

```
TicketSet toAdd;
```

When this function returns, `toAdd` goes out of scope and it's destroyed. That's not what you wanted.

Comment: i've changed to this and now it crashes:
TicketSet* toAdd;
 TicketSetStatus res = tsCreate(toAdd, t.originalTravels, t.cost);
 if (res != TS_SUCCESS) {
  return RQ_FAIL;
 }

 copyTicketSets(toAdd, &t);
 ;  
 rq->tickets[++rq->usedContracts] = *toAdd;
  
 return RQ_SUCCESS;

Comment: The problem with that code is that you never initialize `toAdd`, so you are passing nonsense to `tsCreate`. Since `tsCreate` *creates* a ticket set, you cannot pass it a pointer to a ticket set -- the address isn't known until the set is created.